# Не передается ссылка в request из переменной Python

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста не работает метод get из requests когда ссылку передаю переменной, при этом если ее же передаю просто строкой все работает

```
file_links = open(r'C:\content\links.txt')
while True:
    line = file_links.readline()
    print(line)
    f = open(file_name, "wb")
    ufr = requests.get(line,headers=headers)  # не работает
    ufr = requests.get(r'https://mdkdi.ru/index.php?dispatch=sm_download_excel',headers=headers) # а так работает, но надо именно из переменной, т.к. идет перебор ссылок
    f.write(ufr.content)
    f.close()
    if not line:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот мой код и ссылки из файла прекрасно работают

```py
import requests

with open('links.txt', 'r') as fp:
    cnt = 0;
    for line in fp:
      cnt = cnt + 1
      filename='content_of_link'+str(cnt)+'.html'
      ufr = requests.get(line.rstrip('\n'))
      f = open(filename, 'wb')
      f.write(ufr.content)
      f.close()
```

links.txt:

```
https://www.google.ru
https://www.yandex.ru
https://www.mail.ru
```

Comment: За код извиняйте - не питонист мну :)

Comment: Вот спасибо, все заработало, ура

Comment: Рад, если помог :)